# Compiler can't find SFML/Graphics.hpp?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, include, sfml

I am trying to include the SFML graphics library into my C++ program on VSCode on Mac, I have put the pathname to the include folder in both my tasks.json file as well as my c_cpp_properties.json file and when trying to run the main.cpp file or run the make command I get the error message

```
main.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Below provided is my tasks.json file

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "process",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-Iopt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.82.0_1/include",
                "-Iopt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.0/include",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}/include/boost"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my c_cpp_properties.json file

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.82.0_1/include",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.0/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and finally here is my main.cpp file

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not a VS Code Guru, but I'd expect `"-Iopt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.0/include"` to be `"-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.0/include"`. Same with the path to boost.

Comment: I find myself wondering what more debugging details are required. This looks complete and close to minimal to me.

Comment: I expect your first comment to answer this question. For your second comment I expect someone may want to make sure that the OP checked to see if  `opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.0/include` was the the correct folder. However if they checked that probably lead to them finding that its not because of the missing `/` at the beginning. In either case I didn't vote on this question.